# Save optix denoised viewport render as is?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I am looking for a way to save the optix denoised viewport render as is (view - viewport render image). I was told there was a plugin for 2.79 but I cannot find it.

Would hope there's is a way to achieve that in 2.82.

Thank you!